# jquery login form in div without refreshing whole page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a php-file that i want to put to work in a div:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php function loginForm() { ?>
<form method="POST" action="" name="loginForm" id="loginForm" accept-charset='UTF-8'>
    <input type='hidden' name='submit' id='submit' value='1'/>
    User: <input type="text" name="user" id="user" /><br />
    Password: <input type="password" name="passwd" id="passwd" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="Login" />
</form>
<?php } ?>

<?php function logoutForm() { ?>
    <form method="POST" action="" name="logoutForm" id="logoutForm">
        Logout: <input type="submit" value="Log out" name="logout" id="logout" />
    </form>
<?php } ?>

<?php
function loggedUser() {
    if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && isset($_SESSION['passwd'])) {
        return $_SESSION;
    } else {
        return array();
    }
}

function loginLogout() {
    $loggedUser = loggedUser();
    if(!empty($loggedUser)) {
        logoutForm();
    } else {
        loginForm();
    }
    if(isset($_POST['login']) && isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['passwd']) &&
            $_POST['user'] == "admin" && $_POST['passwd'] == "admin") {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user'];
        $_SESSION['passwd'] = $_POST['passwd'];
        header('Refresh: 1; url='.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    }
    if(isset($_POST['logout']) && isset($_SESSION)) {
        foreach($_SESSION as $k => $v) {
            unset($_SESSION[$k]);
        }
        header('Refresh: 1; url='.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    }
}
loginLogout();

?>
```

And also i have codes in jquery and html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#logindiv').load('loginLogout.php');
        $('#loginForm, #logoutForm').live('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.post('loginLogout.php', $(this).serialize(), function (
                    data, textStatus) {
                $('#logindiv').html(data);
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

and the div

```
<div id="logindiv"></div>
```

How to put correctly the code, that log in and log out works also in jquery without refreshing the whole page? What is a refresh event that recognize a line header('Refresh: 1; url='.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); in the php-file. Widhout div and jquery it works well.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a full working example using 2 files that will allow the login/logout form to update dynamically without a page refresh. The code is very similar to yours.

Code for **form.php**

```
<?php 
session_start(); 

function loginForm($isHidden) { 
    $display = ($isHidden) ? "none" : "block";
    ?>
    <form method="POST" action="" name="loginForm" id="loginForm" accept-charset='UTF-8' style="display: <?php echo $display; ?>;">
        <input type='hidden' name='actionLogin' id='actionLogin' value='1'/>
        User: <input type="text" name="user" id="user" /><br />
        Password: <input type="password" name="passwd" id="passwd" /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="Login" />
    </form>
    <?php 
} 

function logoutForm($isHidden) { 
    $display = ($isHidden) ? "none" : "block";
    ?>
    <form method="POST" action="" name="logoutForm" id="logoutForm" style="display: <?php echo $display; ?>;">
        <input type='hidden' name='actionLogout' id='actionLogout' value='1'/>
        Logout: <input type="submit" value="Log out" name="logout" id="logout" />
    </form>
    <?php 
}

function loggedUser() {
    if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && isset($_SESSION['passwd'])) {
        return $_SESSION;
    } else {
        return array();
    }
}
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Form</title>

    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#loginForm, #logoutForm').live('submit', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.post('loginLogout.php', $(this).serialize(), function (data, textStatus) {
                    if (data == "true") { //login successful
                        $("#loginForm").hide();
                        $("#logoutForm").show();
                    } else {
                        $("#loginForm").show();
                        $("#logoutForm").hide();
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="logindiv">
        <?php
        $loggedUser = loggedUser();
        if(!empty($loggedUser)) {
            loginForm(true); //hidden
            logoutForm(false); //not hidden
        } else {
            loginForm(false);
            logoutForm(true);
        }
        ?>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Code for **loginLogout.php**

```
<?php
session_start(); 

if(isset($_POST['actionLogin']) && isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['passwd']) &&
        $_POST['user'] == "admin" && $_POST['passwd'] == "admin") {
    $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user'];
    $_SESSION['passwd'] = $_POST['passwd'];
    echo "true"; //successful log in

} else if(isset($_POST['actionLogout']) && isset($_SESSION)) {
    foreach($_SESSION as $k => $v) {
        unset($_SESSION[$k]);
    }
    echo "false"; //successful log out
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you responses. These hopefully help me.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to process the form submission **before** it prints out the form. It might seem counter intuitive, but unless you process all input first, the HTML you have printed is already obsolete when it is ready to be sent to the browser.

You also won't need the refresh header if you use ajax.

Just  change your code like this:

```
function loginLogout() {
    if(isset($_POST['login']) && isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['passwd']) &&
            $_POST['user'] == "admin" && $_POST['passwd'] == "admin") {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user'];
        $_SESSION['passwd'] = $_POST['passwd'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['logout']) && isset($_SESSION)) {
        foreach($_SESSION as $k => $v) {
            unset($_SESSION[$k]);
        }
    }
    $loggedUser = loggedUser();
    if(!empty($loggedUser)) {
        logoutForm();
    } else {
        loginForm();
    }
}
```