# How to make a php login form without page refresh if login fails?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My headline allmost says it all, I want to make a login form that will NOT refresh the page if the login fails, but if login success it should direct me to the right page :)

```
<?php
$errormessage = "";
session_start();
if (@$_SESSION['logged_in'] == TRUE) {

    header("Location: index-users.php");
    exit();
}

if ( isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']) ) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'dbname');

    $query = "SELECT * FROM dbname_users WHERE username = '$username' AND  password = '$password'";

    $result = $db->query($query);

    $rows = $result->num_rows;


    if($rows == 1){
        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = TRUE;
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['ID'];
        }
        header("Location: index-users.php");
    }
    else{
        $errormessage = "Forkert brugernavn eller adgangskode!";
    }
}
?>

<form action="login.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
    <p><?=$errormessage;?></p>
</form>
```

Anyone know how to do this? :)

Comment: exactly as you've tagged the question: ajax. And you are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), so enjoy having a completely useless login system anyways, since anyone can bypass it completely.

Comment: Is your question how to perform the AJAX call?

Comment: Use ajax, and depending on the response that you get, decide if you want to redirect the user or not.

Comment: It's not about PHP, its about html&js or jquery

Comment: Please also have a look at the [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function, it helps to store your customers passwords safely.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery login form in div without refreshing whole page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805187/jquery-login-form-in-div-without-refreshing-whole-page)

Answer (score 3):

You will need to combine it with AJAX or jQuery codes. 
It is not only php!

Check this out:
- [jquery login form in div without refreshing whole page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805187/jquery-login-form-in-div-without-refreshing-whole-page)

Answer (score 0):

```
function myBad() {
    $.post("http://localhost/vivsang/logbase.php", {
        login : $("#mylogin").serialize()
    }, function (login) {
        if (login == 'true') {
            window.location = 'home.php';
        } else {
            alert('Wrong username or password!');
        }
    });
```

Use this jQuery code for login. You must understand first where to put it and how to use it.